# SQL query using Firebird and foreign characters causes a malformed string error

Tags: sql, firebird, malformed

I have a simple example that is causing an error using Firebird SQL.

I have a table with a column called Details which is defined as:

```
DETAILS varchar(261) COLLATE UNICODE
```

If I try to do the following query:

```
SELECT a.DETAILS
FROM MODHISTORY a 
WHERE
    a.DETAILS LIKE '%Â%'
```

I get the error:

```
Error: *** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Statement::Prepare( SELECT a.DETAILS
FROM MODHISTORY a 
WHERE
    a.DETAILS LIKE '%Â%'
 )
Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed

SQL Message : -104
Invalid token

Engine Code    : 335544849
Engine Message :
Malformed string
```

If I connect to the database using CHARSET=UTF8 in the connection string this error goes away but unfortunately I cannot use UTF8 as the character set when connecting to the database because some other tables contain, for example:

```
SampleData blob sub_type 1 CHARACTER SET ASCII,
```

Comment: The fact you have columns with a different character set doesn't mean that you can't use UTF8 as a connection character set. However, what connection character set are you using now? The error suggest that you're using connection character set NONE, that the query string `Â` is encoded in - for example - WIN1252, and those raw bytes are then attempted to convert to UTF8, which doesn't work because the byte encoding `Â` in WIN1252 are invalid in UTF8.

Comment: Try using parameters instead of string literals? Or try using binary literals? https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-hexbinstrings.html // but proper way would still be to make connection in a charset compatible with the `UNICODE` collate of the column

Comment: If I add the character set UTF8 to my connection string I get errors when trying to save blob data. Right now we are not specifying a character set in the connection string. Is there any way that I can specify the character set in my SELECT statement? Would that solve my problem?

Comment: How would I use parameters instead of string literals. Can someone give me an example of this?

Comment: If you get errors with connection encoding, then you are saving non-ascii values into those blobs (ASCII only defines characters for bytes 0..127), which pass unnoticed when using connection character set NONE (as that disables a lot of character set checks), or your code/client component is doing something wrong when populating the blob. You could try using the introducer syntax. Eg, if your default encoding is Cp1252, try using `LIKE _win1252'%Â%'. Note though that this only works correctly if the bytes sent to Firebird are actually that encoding, otherwise you may get the wrong char.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem as suggested. I am binding the parameters and now everything works fine

Comment: What is "as suggested"? Please flesh out "binding the parameters". Comments are ephemeral, please make your posts self-contained.